# Image with text slider Responsive

Tags: html, response, slide

Do any one know responsive slider in which image with text can be slide left, right in jquery?
[image]

I want to impliment a slider as shown in the image

Comment: Gooooooooooooooooooogle ..................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Liquid Slider](http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/) can do it! You just need to make sure you style the pictures and text accordingly.